# IoT based warehouse management solution

Tags: rfid, nfc

In our Group of Companies, we are having a Logistics arm which is running services for industry on following domains:

1. Transport and Fleet Management
2. Industry Warehousing

We are looking for IoT based management solutions for the warehouse (RFID, NFC or any other mechanism) operations. Operations include Rapid inventory checking process, Count combined with other processes, Increased stock accuracy, etc

Our warehouses span across country on multiple locations and looking for IoT based solution.

Any suggestions on possible solution available in the market? or we need to develop our own solution?

Comment: This is obviously far too broad to be a valid question within the rules of SE sites, which require that questions state a single, **specific** problem which can be specifically answered.  You do not seem to have a specific problem which you are able to clearly state, but only a general idea that IoT might be relevant to your business.  Thus you are at a point where you should be reading published material; you are not yet at the point of having a question which complies with Stack Exchange rules.